# ZFS SAN boot - what makes the OS crash during SAN switch change

Tags: zfs, solaris-10

I have a Solaris 10 server - with ZFS SAN boot  - the OS pool has disks configured from two different HBAs c1 , c2 - have LUNs from different FA ports  on the SAN array  - c1 , c2 HBAs are connected to different fabric switches - but still if one of the cables is pulled(or fails) seems like the OS is hung  - and needs a powercycle - what is it in ZFS that should be tuned so that there is a smooth failover even if it is a SAN boot

thanks in advance.